# Is there php written in php?

Tags: php, compiler-construction, interpreter

I found that almost language are written in itself, sometimes to just prove it can be done. So is there php interpreter/compiler written in php? I search google but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PHPPHP](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHPPHP) by [ircmaxell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338665/ircmaxell)

[image]

```
<?php // ?>
```